# Basic calendar display in R

Tags: r, date, calendar

Is there a basic calendar display in R, like Unix's `cal` program?

I realize it's not that hard to wrap the base date/time functions (like `weekdays`, `seq.date`, etc.), but I feel like I'm ignorant of something pretty basic that may be solved in one of the outstanding time/date packages that already exist.  Moreover, it always starts simply enough: assign days of the week, but then one gets to leap years, layout for calendars spanning multiple months (though I'd settle for just printing 1 month), and so on.

My current usage involves switching out of R to Linux or a calendar program in Windows.  Doing this in R would be easier.

---

Note 1.  I've looked at some of the various widgets available for Gtk2 and TclTk - for some reason, installation of supporting systems is not working out well (and I think it's serious overkill, nor is it very good from a portability perspective to have such dependencies).  In Windows, I've even tried Cygwin, to access `cal`, but that installation seems to be conflicting with Rtools.  In short, adding layers of stuff is not a particularly productive avenue at the moment.  :)  I've not found any solutions in lubridate, xts, zoo, and other packages, though I may have missed something.

Comment: @kohske -- That's OS-dependent.  Works on UNIX, but not on Windows...

Comment: Exactly. That's why this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @kohske Yep, in addition to being ignorant of R, I didn't want to admit that I sometimes run R on Windows.  It seems I can never fully hide my shame.  :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a function that will do the basic yearly or monthly calendar:

```
cal <- function(month, year) {

        if(!require(chron)) stop('Unable to load chron package')

     if(missing(year) && missing(month)) {
         tmp <- month.day.year(Sys.Date())
         year <- tmp$year
         month <- tmp$month
     }


    if(missing(year) || missing(month)){  # year calendar
        if(missing(year)) year <- month
        par(mfrow=c(4,3))
        tmp <- seq.dates( from=julian(1,1,year), to=julian(12,31,year) )
        tmp2 <- month.day.year(tmp)
        wd <- do.call(day.of.week, tmp2)
        par(mar=c(1.5,1.5,2.5,1.5))
        for(i in 1:12){
            w <- tmp2$month == i
            cs <- cumsum(wd[w]==0)
            if(cs[1] > 0) cs <- cs - 1
            nr <- max( cs ) + 1
            plot.new()
            plot.window( xlim=c(0,6), ylim=c(0,nr+1) )
            text( wd[w], nr - cs -0.5 , tmp2$day[w] )
            title( main=month.name[i] )
            text( 0:6, nr+0.5, c('S','M','T','W','T','F','S') )
        }

    } else {  # month calendar

        ld <- seq.dates( from=julian(month,1,year), length=2, by='months')[2]-1
        days <- seq.dates( from=julian(month,1,year), to=ld)
        tmp <- month.day.year(days)
        wd <- do.call(day.of.week, tmp)
        cs <- cumsum(wd == 0)
        if(cs[1] > 0) cs <- cs - 1
        nr <- max(cs) + 1
        par(oma=c(0.1,0.1,4.6,0.1))
        par(mfrow=c(nr,7))
        par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
        for(i in seq_len(wd[1])){ 
            plot.new()
            #box()
        }
        day.name <- c('Sun','Mon','Tues','Wed','Thur','Fri','Sat')
        for(i in tmp$day){
            plot.new()
            box()
            text(0,1, i, adj=c(0,1))
            if(i < 8) mtext( day.name[wd[i]+1], line=0.5,
                at=grconvertX(0.5,to='ndc'), outer=TRUE ) 
        }
        mtext(month.name[month], line=2.5, at=0.5, cex=1.75, outer=TRUE)
        #box('inner') #optional 
    }
}
```

You can edit various pieces to customize it.  You can use `par(mfg=c(r,c))` to add text, plots, or other info to a given cell in the monthly calendar (see `updateusr` and `subplot` in the `TeachingDemos` package for possible aid in adding a plot).

Here are some examples of adding text or plots to the calendar:

```
cal(10,2011)
par(mfg=c(3,2))  # monday oct 10
text(.5,.5, 'Some\nText', cex=2)

par(mfg=c(2,3)) #Tues oct 4
text(1,1, 'Top Right', adj=c(1,1))

par(mfg=c(2,4)) # Wed oct 5
text(0,0, 'Bottom Left', adj=c(0,0))

par(mfg=c(6,2)) # oct 31
tmp.x <- runif(25)
tmp.y <- rnorm(25,tmp.x,.1)
par(usr=c( range(tmp.x), range(tmp.y) ) )
points(tmp.x,tmp.y)
```

Comment: +1 That is very cool.  That also introduces a lot of functions that I was unaware of.

Comment: Looks like this is the best answer I'll get, but I only need one.  :)  I encourage you to put it in a little package - it's very useful, or in your own `TeachingDemos` package.  I am surprised that I'm not already familiar with this one.  Thanks!

Comment: @Greg you said you could add text ect. to a cell. would you mind giving us a couple of examples demonstrating this capability?

Comment: I added this piece of code to make the function return the calendar of the current month when no arguments are supplied. `if(missing(year)& missing(month)){
        month=as.numeric(which(month.abb==substr(date(),5,7)))
        year=as.numeric(substr(date(),23,24))
    }`

Comment: I added some code to the function to default to the current month if no arguments are supplied and added some examples of adding to the plot of the current month.  Notice that each cell has coordinates from 0 to 1 in both x and y directions unless you set them to be different.

Comment: A plot of the day!  I love it.  I could log the best plot I've made each day and present it in my own calendar.  That could (and should?) inspire me to do more and better plots.

Comment: +1 Neat, but I'd go with the POSIXlt to avoid using chron. It has some irritating side effects as it overwrites some functions in other packages. I moved away from it.

Comment: I have taken the above suggestions and added a modified version (does not use chron anymore) to the TeachingDemos package (currently only the version on R-forge, not on CRAN yet).  It also now returns a function that if run with a day of the month number will set the current plotting frame to the corresponding day.